# Optimization of a jQuery code

Tags: jquery, optimization, query-optimization

I try here to detect the select of `option[name='admin']` and if it's, then I check the mentioned checkbox if not I uncheck it.

Is there a better optimization of this code?

```
$("select option[name='admin']:selected").select(function () {
    $(".gestionSupervision").prop('checked', true);
});

$("select option[name='sei']:selected").select(function () {
    $(".gestionSupervision").prop('checked', false);
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<select name="role" id="role" class="form-control" disabled>
    <option value="admin">Administrateur</option>
    <option value="sei">Superviseur</option>
</select>
```

Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code for easier to understand:

```
$('select#role').on('change', function (e) {
    var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this),
        selectedVal = this.value;

    if(selectedVal == "admin") {
        $(".gestionSupervision").prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $(".gestionSupervision").prop('checked', false);
    }
}).change();
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/45VEL/)**

Or you can shorten above code to:

```
$('select#role').on('change', function (e) {
    var selectedVal = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    $(".gestionSupervision").prop('checked', selectedVal == "admin");
}).change();
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/45VEL/1/)**

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, I've upvoted it !

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use the change event

```
$("#role").change(function () {
    $(".gestionSupervision").prop('checked', $(this).find('option[value="admin"]').is(':selected'));
}).change();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/989Zp/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, I've upvoted it !

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this:

```
$("select option:selected").select(function () {
    status = (this.val() == 'sei')
    $(".gestionSupervision").prop('checked', status);
});
```

No need to repeat the whole thing and change only the names/booleans.